# Python Files word count and character count

Tags: python, function, file

**Picture of Question:**

[image]

I have this code but it just outputs a blank file. What am I doing wrong?

```
def lineStats(infile, outfile):
    inF = open(infile, 'rt')
    outF = open(outfile, 'wt')
    content = inF.readlines()
    for line in inF:
        wordcount = len(line.split())
        charcount = len(line)
        outF.write(str(wordcount) + ' ' + str(charcount))
    inF.close()
    outF.close()

lineStats('promisedLand.txt', 'promisedLandStats.txt')
```

Comment: Creating another user id won't work. The folks who run this place are programming and web site experts and know how to prevent that sort of behavior.

Comment: Posting pictures of questions is discouraged as it makes the content impossible to index and therefore useless for future visitors to search.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems, you're consuming your file when you do the following (delete this line):

```
content = inF.readlines()
```

And you forgot to write newlines each time you call `write`:

```
outF.write(str(wordcount) + ' ' + str(charcount) + '\n')
```